# Git Ignore everything in a directory except subfolders

Tags: git, gitignore, subdirectory

This is my folder structure:

```
data/
    .gitignore
    uploads/
        .gitignore
```

I would like to commit the folders but not the files inside them.

So I add a .gitignore files in every folder with the following content:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

The problem is that `*` matches also on directories so git tracks only `data/.gitignore`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The solution is quite easy, add `!*/` to the .gitignore files and only files in the current folder will be ignored

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
# Except folders
!*/
```

Answer (score 107):

Please don't *misuse* `.gitignore` files. Better stick to default ways to go on this, so later developers can quickly get into your project.

1. Add an empty `.gitkeep` file in the folders that you want to commit without the files
2. Exclude the folders, but not the `.gitkeep` from your **main** `.gitignore` file.

   ```
   folder/*
   !folder/.gitkeep
   ```

This ignores all files in a folder, but not the `.gitkeep` file. Now the folder will be commited with only the `.gitkeep` file as content.

Comment: What misuse is that? He has a perfectly legit need, and @nickel715 is solving it nicely, with a hack of a similar complexity than the one you are proposing ...

Comment: Because a `.gitignore` tells every later developer _that s/he has to look at that file_ just to see nothing that gets ignored. `.gitignore` files also aren't meant to be set to any directory than the main directory. If you would do so, then everyone would have to look through all subfolders to see if there's anything ignored (and find out that there's nothing ignored) to see what actually ends up in the repo or in a deployment pipeline. Don't add unnecessary complexity for later developers _just because you are lazy_ and don't follow conventions.

Comment: Still ignores subdirectories. -1

Comment: Ok, @CommaToast do you have a reproducible example?

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
*.*
!.gitignore
!*/*
```