# How can i include only specific folders in git using .gitignore?

Tags: git, git-branch, gitignore

So i would like ignore everything except a file and a specific folder:

```
rben@ubuntu:~/sites$ ls
development-box  puppet  sites  Vagrantfile  www-cms  www-common  www-mmfa
rben@ubuntu:~/sites$ cat .gitignore
*
!Vagrantfile
!puppet/
rben@ubuntu:~/sites$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       Vagrantfile
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I am expecting to see puppet in the list of untracked files. How can i include only the directory  puppet?

Comment: What if you say `!puppet/*` instead? (Maybe the `!` doesn't work with the `/` directly.)

Comment: Say, I just discovered `git-check-ignore` which can help you debug.

Comment: @matt No `!` also works with `/` see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18930104/1171460

Answer (score 27, accepted):

ok nice, try the following gitignore file:

```
# Ignore everything in repository root 
/*

# Files to not ignore
!/.gitignore
!/some_other_files

# Folder to not ignore
!/puppet/
```

The key point is the slash before the `*`.

In your case the `*` affected also to the files in `puppet`.

So to be on the safe side use absolute paths like in my example

I asked a similar question a while ago: [Git Ignore everything in a directory except subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930103/git-ignore-everything-in-a-directory-except-subfolders)